Deploy Profiles without changing related objects, fields, etc
I'm working on a tool for cleaning up and refactoring profiles and permission sets. This tool uses the Salesforce CLI (sf project retrieve start) to retrieve a wide array of metadata (including objects, fields, Apex classes, Lightning Pages, page layouts, etc., etc.) to the user's local machine. This metadata is then parsed to get a comprehensive view of existing settings and permissions related to each profile and permission set.
I imagine that when users are using my tool, it will take them at least a few days to finalize a refactor. In the meantime, it's possible that the metadata they retrieved initially will have become stale. For example, someone may have added a new picklist value to a field, or updated an existing Apex class.
The goal is to allow users to deploy Profile CRUD access (e.g. access to a field) without deploying changes to the items being accessed (e.g. the field itself), so any recent changes (outside of Profiles and Permission Sets) don't get overwritten. Is this possible?
Note: We use Copado Essentials at my company, and I've noted that they offer a Deploy Type called "Profiles Only", which I understand to be doing exactly the thing I'm currently trying to do. But I don't know the technical details behind it.

In short, no it's not possible. The CLI will truncate the Profile metadata that is being deployed, and will drop out any references to objects not being deployed. For Permission Sets, we don't have that issue as they are deployed in full every time. One thing to note though, is that with the coming deprecation of permissions on Profiles, it might not be a problem that will impact users of the tool for long.

Yeah, this effort was initially prompted by the deprecation you mentioned, but that seems to have been indefinitely suspended. So I'm not holding my breath :P
